# spring boot repository not returning real entity

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am having a entities including inheritence, which are similar built up like in the article here: http://blog.netgloo.com/2014/12/18/handling-entities-inheritance-with-spring-data-jpa/

My abstract Base Class is a Promotion and the a Subclass is AssortmentPromotion.

In my mapper function I am calling the following code:

```
Promotion promotion = promotionRepository
                                .findById(source.getPromotion().getId())
                                .orElseThrow(() -> new BadRequestException("Invalid Promotion"));
```

Now the promotion variable is not a valid AssortmentPromotion as you can see in the image below. Also `promotion instanceof AssortmentPromotion` returns false.

[image: Not A real promotion]

Any idea what I could do to get a real entitiy object?

Comment: Hibernate uses proxies. The returned proxy is a Promotion, and accessing it polymorphically (i.e. without using instanceof and casts) will work fine. What's the concrete problem? Why are you using instanceof?

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate uses [javassist](http://www.javassist.org/) to enhance and proxy the entity classes. This is mostly done for the lazy loading "magic" of associated entities (@ManyToOne, @OneToOne).

There a numerous articles how this is done and how you can unproxy such an entity: 
https://vladmihalcea.com/how-does-a-jpa-proxy-work-and-how-to-unproxy-it-with-hibernate/

```
org.hibernate.Hibernate.unproxy(promotion);
```

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/Hibernate.html#unproxy-java.lang.Object-